# How to write into a file with columns that are separated by 5 tabs

Tags: python

How can I write 100 to 1000 in a file with columns that are separated by 5 tabs? Here is the code that I tried:

output.txt file should look like below:

```
100-5tabs-101-5tabs-102-5-tabs-103-5-tabs-104\n
105-5tabs-106-5tabs-107-5-tabs-108-5-tabs-109
```

Code:

```py
    def writing_numbers():
        with open("output.txt","w") as f:
            for i in range (100,1001):
                f.write(str(i))
                f.write('\t'*5)
```

If I use above code, it does not maintain column when I use 'wrap' in notepad. What can I improve in the code to be independent of wrap view in nodepad

Comment: I don't see `f.write('\n')` anywhere.

Comment: @David, Just to show how the output should look like, I've used \n. I just want to have output separated by 5 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED - Try this:

```
def writing_numbers():
    with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
        for i in range (100, 1001):
            if i%3 == 0:
                f.write(f"{i}\n")
            else:
                f.write(f'{i}' + '\t'*5)
```

Comment: getting bellow error when I run this SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash

Comment: this code does not work if I use wrap if I change if statement to i%5 and make \t to 15

Comment: That was not what you asked. What exactly do you want?